# What's the running time of this "compute all palindrome substrings" algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue, palindrome

```
   public PriorityQueue<String> findPalindromesSubstring(String string) {
        PriorityQueue<String> palindromes = new PriorityQueue<>();
        string = string.replace("","#");
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { //n iterations
            int j = 0;
            while (i-j >= 0 && i+j < string.length() && string.charAt(i-j) == string.charAt(i+j)) {
                String palindrome = string.substring(i-j, i+j+1);
                if (palindrome.charAt(0) != '#') {
                    palindromes.add(palindrome.replace("#", ""));
                }
                j++;
            }

        }
        return palindromes;
    }
```

I used a PriorityQueue because I need the palindrome substrings sorted alphabetically. At the moment I don't care about duplicates, but I am not sure about the worst case running time the result, from my understanding it is something like

`n (chars in string because of for loop)`

*

`n (max possible length of a palindrome because of inner while loop/2)`

*

`log(max number of palindromes because of PriorityQueue's add operation)`

So the running time is `O(n^2*logn)` ? Or should I replace one of the n with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running time complexity is `O(N^3*log(N^2))`. 
Let's take a closer look at `palindromes.add(palindrome.replace("#", ""));` `replace` function takes `O(n)`, `add` function makes `O(lg N^2)` comparisons (because we have at most `N^2` palindromes, so height of heap is `lg N^2`). Each comparison of a string takes `O(N)` so total time of this line is `O((log N^2) * N + N)`

Comment: You are right about the logn^2, but why we have at most N^2 palindromes?

Comment: We may have at most `n` palindromes length `1`, `n - 1` palindromes length `2`, ..., `2` pallindromes length `n - 1`, `1` palindrome length `n`, so we have `n + n - 1 + ... + 2 + 1 = n * (n + 1) / 2` palindromes in total, you can easly verify it by invoking `findPalindromesSubstring("aaaa")`. `n * (n + 1) / 2 = O(n^2)`